Importar librerías de una impresora HPRT
podrían ayudarme a cambiar este código de una clase java que importa librerías zebra a las de una impresora a HPRT, estoy desarrollando mi proyecto en windev mobile y no encuentro el código apropiado por favor. adjunto el código para la impresora zebra si funciona y la impresora HPRT HM-A300E que quiero añadir



1- el código va en formato texto. 2- deberías poner lo que has intentado. Saludos
